# How to execute a command by default starting tmux?

Tags: bash, tmux

- I need to execute a command by default when tmux start a new session.
- I need to start by default in a folder when session start.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use a script to start tmux. Saving the following to a bash script (or whatever shell you are using, remembering to fix the hash-bang (#!)), making it executable and then executing the script will get you a new tmux session with a single window running vim. Adjust the session and window names, and the command to your taste.

```
#!/bin/bash
tmux new-session -d -s mySession -n myWindow
tmux send-keys -t mySession:myWindow "cd /my/directory" Enter
tmux send-keys -t mySession:myWindow "vim" Enter
tmux attach -t mySession:myWindow
```

Comment: I should credit [Greg Hurrell](https://github.com/wincent/wincent/blob/master/.tmux) where I originally got this from.

Comment: I've got error message: duplicate session: mySession

Comment: You probably need to kill the existing session first

Comment: how do you execute this script?

Comment: After saving it as a file in the current directory (as script-name.sh for example), make it executable (chmod +x script-name.sh), then run the script like this: `./script-name.sh`.